# Find the limit points of the following sets in $R$

Tags: real-analysis

> Determine all the limit points of the following sets in $\mathbb{R}$ .
>
> 1) All numbers of the form $2^{-n}$ + $5^{-m}$ (m, n = 1,2,$...$)
>
> 2) All numbers of the form $(-1)^n + (\frac 1m)$ (m, n = 1,2,$...$)
>
> 3) All numbers of the form $(\frac 1n) + (\frac 1m)$ (m, n = 1,2,$...$)
>
> 4) All numbers of the form $\frac{(-1)^n}{[1+\frac 1n]}$ (n = 1,2,$...$)

I'm having trouble finding out the limit points of sets like these when there are two free variables. How can I find out the limit points in these cases? Thanks.

Comment: Fix one and see what happens.

Comment: I don't see how to rigorously prove that finding out the limit point with one variable fixed leads to the answer can anyone answer this question thorougly?

Comment: @user135204. In case of 1) as the set $5^{-m}$ and $2^{-n}$ zero is a limit point. That means every every point of the form $2^-n$ and $5^{-m}$ and also zero are limit points of the set. That must be what they meant by fixing one set and see what happens.

Comment: @boywholived Intuitively I get it but I don't know how to show they must be the only limit points.